# Select the second col_content

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a problem with selectors. I checked online how to select the second .col_content in my code to give it a particular bg-image. I know I can just add a second class, but just to know how can I pick right it with CSS selectors, if this is possible of course. I tried many selectors without success. Is there a solution to this?

P.S If classes names create confusion, this is a raw framework I've built, since I'm learning responsiveness right now

```
<section id="slides">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="col_inner">
                    <div class="col_content">
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h3>HelbizGo</h3>
                            <p>Next generation of electric city bikes.</p>
                            <a href="#">Learn more ></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                <div class="col_inner">
                    <div class="col_content">
                        <div class="product-text">
                            <h3>HelbizGo</h3>
                            <p>Next generation of electric city bikes.</p>
                            <a href="#">Learn more ></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#slides > div:nth-child(3) .col_content` is required but note that this is **extremely fragile** and another class would the optimal solution.